# Retrieving data from multiple table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, queryover

I have 2 tables namely Library and Book

- In Library ->lid , lname,laddress and Setbooks(lid is primary
  key)
- In Books->bid,bname,bauthor(bid is primary key)

I.e.: library--one to many-->Book
I'm finding difficulty in retrieving List of Library s having books of author(bauthor) ="xyz".

I have tries this query:

```
query=session.createQuery("from Library as l where l.books.bauthor="xyz");
```

But getting error: illegal attempt to dereference collection in hibernate query list

when I used this query:

```
query=session.createQuery("from Library as l inner join l.books b where b.bauthor="xyz");
List<Library>list=query.list();
```

I'm getting correct no. of books but when I tried to retrieve `(Library l=list.get(0);or Library l=(Library)list.get(0))`

I'm getting error:  `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.demo.Library`.

Comment: Do you understand `ClassCastException`?

Comment: s but how can i convert Object into Library Object?

Comment: use Object instead, check out what type `list()` returns, debug it, get actual type, then typecast

Comment: Can you please post your hibernate mappings for Library and Book. Then we can see how to best structure your query.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Library and Book type list so you can get only one type record

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            records = query.list();
            for (Object[] fields : records) {
                Library view = new Library();
                view.setId(StringUtils.toString(fields[1]));
                view.setLName(StringUtils.toString(fields[0]));
                list.add(view);
            }
```

Comment: thanks Mohammod,i have changed StringUtils.toString(fields[1])  to fields[1].toString() it worked

Comment: It will not work, because you don't know what is `StringUtils`.

Comment: it worked, but if i  use StringUtils it shows compilation error

Comment: StringUtils is an util class that I used for my own purpose.You can any method to covert objet into string

Comment: OK this answer is all over the place. What is createSQLQuery doing here? This is not the right approach.

Comment: You have to create view model of Book and Library and return list return view type